# How to force an HTTPS callback using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Google?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nginx, asp.net-identity, google-authentication

I am creating an AspNetCore application with Google authentication.  I am deploying this app behind an nginx reverse proxy on an Ubuntu server.  *Almost* everything is working, but I am having trouble with the callback url.

In the Google developer console, I have http://localhost:5000/signin-google set as an authorized redirect URI.  This works as expected and allows me to use Google authentication when running from my workstation.

For production, I have https://myserver/signin-google set as an authorized redirect URI.  However, when I try to use it, I get an error from accounts.google.com that http://myserver/signin-google (notice the missing s) is not authorized.  That's true; it shouldn't be authorized and my server doesn't even respond to port 80 requests.

How can I tell the authentication middleware that I need it to use HTTPS for the callback URL?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I finally figured it out.

Step 1: Make sure Nginx is sending the necessary forwarding headers, for example:

```
server {
    # other stuff ...
    location / {
        # other stuff ...
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        # you could also just hardcode this to https if you only accept https
    }
}
```

Step 2: By default, AspNetCore will ignore these headers.  Install the middleware that processes it:

```
PM> Install-Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpOverrides
```

Step 3: in your `Configure` function, apply the middleware.

```
app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
{
    ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
});
```

This should correctly change the `Context.Request.Scheme` value to https, which will cause the authentication middleware to generate the correct `redirect_uri`.

Comment: Thank you soooo much. This post has fixed a long standing bug in our app!