# Insecure Login Blocked

Tags: facebook-login, asp.net-core-2.1, facebook-authentication

I am working on a site (which the name is https://tutumluannev2test.derinpos.com/). I've been trying to add facebook login. At localhost no problem but at staging, I always get this error message:

> Insecure Login Blocked: You can’t get an access token or log in to this app from an insecure page. Try reloading the page as https://

- it's a **ASP.NET Core 2.1** project.
- served by **nginx** from ubuntu 16.04
- **Valid OAuth Redirect URIs**: https://tutumluannev2test.derinpos.com/signin-facebook
- https://www.facebook.com/v2.12/dialog/oauth?client_id=201510504064809&scope=public_profile%2Cemail&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Ftutumluannev2test.derinpos.com%2Fsignin-facebook&state=...

nginx.conf:

```
server {
    listen 80 
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name   tutumluannev2test.derinpos.com;
    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-SSL on;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Protocol $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;    
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5003;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
    }
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains; preload";
    add_header X-Frame-Options DENY;
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/tutumluannev2test.derinpos.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/tutumluannev2test.derinpos.com/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

}
```

Can anybody help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The `redirect_uri` parameter in the login dialog call must be a HTTPS URL, but currently it is a HTTP one. If this is automatically generated by some component, then you probably need to specify some sort of base URL somewhere correctly to include HTTPS there already.

Comment: I shared nginx config in particular. I don't know why my return uri is changed as HTTP. how can I include base URL or which config (startup.cs or nginx.conf) should be changed?

Comment: Impossible to say, since you have given us no info whatsoever what library you are using for the OAuth stuff there, resp. where/how you are creating this login dialog URL (in case you are doing that yourself somehow.)

Comment: I use default AddFacebook config in startup.cs. i didn't set callback url in it. My ConfigureServices like this,

services.AddFacebook(facebookOptions => {
           facebookOptions.AppId = Configuration["Authentication:Facebook:AppId"];
           facebookOptions.AppSecret = Configuration["Authentication:Facebook:AppSecret"];
           facebookOptions.Events = new OAuthEvents ...

Comment: I found a solution, Thanks @name fizzbuzz97  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38360300/6277188) .